# Makefile from Fortran fixed-form and free-from files

Tags: makefile, fortran

I need to make a program from some fixed and free files including some modules.
I've added the `all` instruction in the beginning of makefile.
Then I need to compile several `.f90` files (they contain several modules).
And then I added a rule to compile the `.f` files.

When I ran make it tries to compile the `.f` files first.
What should I change/add?

I use gfortran as a compiler.

Makefile looks like the following:

```
All: exename

Firstf90.o: Firstf90.f90
<tab>gfortran -c $<
Secondf90.o: Second.f90 
<tab>gfortran -c $<
%.o: %.f
<tab>gfortran -c $^

exename: *.o
<tab>gfortran -o exename $^
```

Comment: You may need to have your makefile included so people can better understand the question. have you tried removing .f files? Often they are created from .for files if you have D-lines or #ifdef in a preprocessor sense.

Comment: Sorry, added an example

Comment: These files are original, no instruction in preprocessor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the line:

```
exename: *.o
```

You tell `make` that `exename` is dependent on all files with the extension `.o`. But until you create your first `.o` file, there are none, which means that `make` thinks that it depends on nothing at all.

The annoying thing is that once the object files exist, this `Makefile` does exactly what you'd expect, which makes it hard to notice that there's anything wrong with it.

Try something like this:

```
FIXED_SOURCES = $(wildcard *.f) 
FREE_SOURCES = $(wildcard *.f90)
FIXED_OBJECTS = $(patsubst %.f,%.o,${FIXED_SOURCES})
FREE_OBJECTS = $(patsubst %.f90,%.o,${FREE_SOURCES})

all : exename

${FIXED_OBJECTS} : %.o : %.f
<tab>gfortran -o $@ -c $^

${FREE_OBJECTS} : %.o : %.f90
<tab>gfortran -o $@ -c $^

exename : ${FIXED_OBJECTS} ${FREE_OBJECTS}
<tab>gfortran -o $@ $^
```

*Note:* Normally I'd test it before posting it, but I can't at the moment. Plus, someone might have a more concise `Makefile` for you.

Answer (score 0):

> When I ran make it tries to compile f files first.

Is that a problem? If you need to compile them in a certain way, i.e. because of modules, you can add the dependencies to the `Makefile`. Say `mymod.f90` creates a module that is used by `prog.f90`. So you need to compile `mymod.f90` before you can compile `prog.f90`. Simple: Add this line to the `Makefile`:

```
prog.o : mymod.o
```

This declares `mymod.o` to be a prerequisite to `prog.o`, meaning that before `prog.o` is compiled, first `mymod.o` is checked whether it exists and is up to date.

Comment: And a clean section to remove .o .mod, and .lib files... etc. the. If you make clean, followed by make everything will be fresh.